# File upload in Directus

Tags: reactjs, directus

So i'm trying to upload pdf files to directus. In postman it's working fine and uploads successfully on my React project i keep getting "You are not allowed to upload files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

1. Could be cors problem
2. Could be that you overwrite your token via postman

Answer (score 0):

From the official Directus API Docs:

> By default, all data in the system is off limits for unauthenticated users. To gain access to protected data, **you must include an access token with every request**.

*Source: https://docs.directus.io/api/authentication.html*

---

I don't know how your project is structured, but if you're *already* authenticated within your (Web)app and want to upload using Axios or similar, you should pass the temporary *or* static token that you've *already got* to the library or method that sends the file (Header -> `Authorization: bearer xxtokenxx`).

If you still have questions, the documentation link above has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your role and based on your role check permissions
2. generate a new auth token and try it.